# PDF in edit mode using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, pdf, c#-4.0, itext, pdf-generation

i have a pdf and which has some editable fields. After filling the pdf using iTextSharp and i'll give the option to download the pdf to users. But i need the fields in pdf to be in editable mode after user download it so that he can make any changes required.

How to do it using iTextSharp.
i tried below code but not working

pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;

Please advise.

Comment: *"but not working"* - that is not a very precise description, is it?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).